# Calendar in Time sheet application using asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make Time Sheet application using asp.net mvc3.
Time Sheet should have as input parameters Employee ID and Date, and after that employee will insert project that he was working on and hours spent.
I don't know how to design a calendar in time sheet class, so that one can insert his activities for that day into time sheet and look for previous time sheets, change them. it should look similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTqaL.jpg

Comment: Your question is a bit open ended. I'd suggest using one of the existing jQuery/javascript calendar plugins as a start, there's no point in reinventing the wheel. Implement that in a partial view and you'll be well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a partial view as you you want (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTqaL.jpg) for your time sheet.
you have to use CSS and jquery API for inserting, updating, deleting entries.
your partial view will take parameter employee id, date, also onle list of projects that he is associates.

Answer (score 0):

I am  also working Time Sheet application using asp.net webform. I am using one of the existing jQuery/javascript calendar plugins for pickup date.